# JS: Determining neighbouring countries

Tags: maps, geocoding, javascript

I am looking for a way to determine the neighbouring countries of a country using Javascript. So far I looked around the Google Maps Geocoding API where I could not find what I need.

Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to achieve that without opening Google Maps and looking them up for any single country in the world, which I don't intend to.

I was more thinking of a function that allows me to do something like

```
getNeighbouringCountriesOf("DE"); //returns array like ["AT","NL","CZ", "..."]
```

Please let me know if you know of something like that.

Comment: Licence permitting, find a page like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_territories_by_land_and_maritime_borders, scrape and store the list of adjacent countries in a JavaScript object. There's no point in trying to determine it algorithmically.

Comment: i guess i'll do it that way then.. thanks for your answer!